# How to make a parameterized multibranch pipeline trigger?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, multibranch-pipeline

Can you please give me an example of how should the Jenkinsfile config look to be triggered by a curl http trigger-buildwithparameters? I have tried:

```
properties([parameters(
[string(defaultValue: 'nothing', 
        description: 'gitcommit', 
        name: 'somecommit')])])
```

but it seems that this pipeline won't be triggered by buildwithparameters with a @somecommit parameter. Can bitbucket branch source/multibranch pipelines be triggered by a remote http calls with passed parameters?